# Skype Fixed Width for Posts with Multiple Columns

Tags: excel, skype

I am not sure if this qualifies as a good question, but I have a report from Excel that should be communicated through Skype. The Excel data format is below:

[image]

I posted it on Skype and the format is really bad (see below).

[image]

For some, aesthetics matter. So is there a way to retain the column width and spacing from Excel to Skype?

Comment: Haven't personally used Skype in ages, but you might try saving a copy of the excel file as "Text (Tab Delimited)", which should give you nice tab spacing between the column data. It's not a perfect solution; though with Skype, I'm not sure there's going to be one.

Comment: @Thebluefish thanks! I've found no possible 'solution' as regards Skype columns. Maybe I should try a different approach.